# Why processing.getObject return None in Qgis 2.18.0?

Tags: pyqgis

It 's really weird, I'm working again on a pyqgis script who well worked 3 months ago. But now it returns me this error :

```
File "<string>", line 87, in zonage
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extent'
```

My script line 89 and just before :

```
    #ENVELOPPE  CONCAVE
    enveloppe = processing.runalg('qgis:concavehull', reproj_1['OUTPUT'], 0.25, False, False, None, progress=None)

    #ENTENT DE L'ENVELOPPE
    layer = processing.getObject(enveloppe['OUTPUT'])
    ext = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(layer.extent().xMinimum(), layer.extent().xMaximum(), layer.extent().yMinimum(), layer.extent().yMaximum())
```

So I tried to print `layer` and it returned `None`... it's normal that layer haven't extent, indeed.

Earlier in my script, I also use `processing.getObject` with a processing output and it well works.

```
        #REPROJECTION EN L93
    reproj_1 = processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', point, 'EPSG:2154', None, progress=None)


    #CALCULE DE L ANGLE MOYEN DES RANGS DE LA PARCELLE
        #Definition couche active
    layer = processing.getObject(reproj_1['OUTPUT'])
```

When I print `layer` for this part, I have an object `<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x11b9fa510>`

Somebody can help to solve this issue ?

Comment: Could you download a more recent version of 2.18 and try again? It could be a bug specific to that version.

Comment: Ok I will try. When I wrote this script (I'm on macOS) I had 2.18.9 and for some reasons I tried 2.18.14. Because of some bugs on 2.18.14 (saga disappeared...) I  downgraded to 2.18.0, 2.18.9 wasn't available anymore.

Comment: Great ! my script work again with Qgis 2.18.14 ! But as I said, Saga disappeared from processing...